# How to set default PathValue in a Spring REST service

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm trying to create a dynamic rest service, accepting one or more dynamic PathVariable. How can I set default PathVariable in case none is specified?

```
    @GetMapping(value={"/dynamic","/dynamic/{cognome}","/dynamic/{cognome}/{nome}"})
   public String salutoDinamico(
           @PathVariable(value="nome")@Value("Bar") String nome,
           @PathVariable(value="cognome")@Value("Foo") String cognome

   ) {
       return "Ciao Mondo da "+cognome+" "+" "+nome;
   }
```

Comment: `@PathVariables` has a `required` attribute. Set it to false and provide the default value as needed.

Comment: Are you trying to set a *default value*, to say that not all of them are required without defaults, or something else? Usually you'd have separate controller methods. (And `value=` isn't needed if that's the only annotation parameter.)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to specify separate `@GetMappings` that has no variables at all

Answer (score 0):

you can do this manualy like:

```
 @GetMapping(value={"/dynamic","/dynamic/{cognome}","/dynamic/{cognome}/{nome}"})
   public String salutoDinamico(
           @PathVariable(value="nome",  required=false)String nome,
           @PathVariable(value="cognome",  required=false)String cognome

   ) { 
       if(nom == null){
         nom = "default value - nome";
       }
       if(cognome == null){
          cognome= "default value - cognome";
       }
       return "Ciao Mondo da "+cognome+" "+" "+nome;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `PathVariable` annotation has an attribute named `required`.
Set that attribute to false for optional values.
Also, the Apache `StringUtils` class has helpful functionality for defaulting things.

Try this:

```
@GetMapping("/dynamic/{cognome}/{nome}"})
public String salutoDinamico(
    @PathVariable(value="nome", required=false)@Value("Bar") String nome,
    @PathVariable(value="cognome", required=false)@Value("Foo") String cognome )
{ 
  final String nomeValue = StringUtils.defaultIfBlank(nome, "defaultNome");
  final String cognomeValue = StringUtils.defaultIfBlank(cognome, "defaultCognome";

  return "Ciao Mondo da " + cognome + "  " + nome;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have optional path variables, but you can have two controller methods which call the same service code:

```
 @GetMapping(value={"/dynamic","/dynamic/{cognome}","/dynamic/{cognome}/{nome}"})
       public String salutoDinamico(
               @PathVariable(value="nome")@Value("Bar") String nome,
               @PathVariable(value="cognome")@Value("Foo") String cognome) {
           return "Your Return Here;
       }
```

And Solution goes as follows

```
@GetMapping(value={"/dynamic","/dynamic/{cognome}","/dynamic/{cognome}/{nome}"})
           public String salutoDinamico() {
               return "Your Null Return Here;
           }
```

If you have more than one or max two optional path elements you should seriously consider switching a few of them to request parameters.